# Как получить заголовок активного окна в консоли?

Tags: c#

Какие есть способы получения заголовков из всех истоков ( браузеры, текстовики и.т.п).

Comment: Посмотрите это [решение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115868/how-do-i-get-the-title-of-the-current-active-window-using-c) в англоязычной ветке.

Answer (score 0):

Получилось сделать что-то вроде этого :) Работает нормально.

```
internal class Program
{
  [STAThread]
  private static void Main()
  {
     Console.WriteLine(GetWindow());
  }

  private static bool GetWindow()
  {
     var capacity = 256;
     var sb = new StringBuilder(capacity);

     while (true)
     {
        capacity = (int)SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_GETTEXTLENGTH, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero) + 1 /* \0 char */;

        if (sb.Capacity < capacity)
        {
            sb = new StringBuilder(capacity);
        }
        else
        {
            sb.Clear();
        }

        capacity = (int)SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), WM_GETTEXT, (IntPtr)sb.Capacity, sb);

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString(0, capacity));

        Thread.Sleep(300);
    }
  }
     private const uint WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D;
     private const uint WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E;

     [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
     private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
     private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint uMsg, IntPtr wParam, StringBuilder lParam);

     [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
     private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
```

Но вот вопрос появился: Как сделать чтобы ловил только определённые окна?

Чем можно заменить **GetForegroundWindow**?